# JSSC does not blinking led light in Arduino

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

I am trying to connect **arduino with java** by using **serial communication**. I used a *jssc* library for this purpose. But When I run the java program and send the **string "1"** then led does not glow and  it should continuously glow. But when I send the **string "1"** from **arduino serial monitor** it then glows continuously until I send any other string. **What Should I do to get the same result in java as it is in **Arduino Serial plotter**.** 
Here is my code for Java in **Netbeans**.

```
package javajssctest;

import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

/**
 *
 * @author Abdullah Sajid
 */
public class JavaJSSCTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SerialPort serialport = new SerialPort("COM4");
        try{
            serialport.openPort();
            serialport.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
            serialport.writeString("1");
            serialport.closePort();

        }
        catch(SerialPortException ex){
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

and here is my arduino code.

```
String input;
void setup() {
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
if(Serial.available()>0){
  input = (char)Serial.read();
  if(input=="1"){
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

- The led will never "blink", because you keep reading, but once you set the state, you never reset it and this means that the LED will stay on. What happens is that you check if there is data available, you find a "1" and you turn on the LED. The next time the loop is executed there will be no data available on the serial port, so nothing will happen and the LED will stay on.
- You should make sure that Arduino is receiving the data correctly, so check that the serial port is actually `COM4`. Also, maybe you should use `write` instead of `writestring`. Check [this page](https://coderanch.com/t/483885/java-io/java/Reading-writing-serial-port), for example.

Comment: Dear ChatterOne, I know there are only two states whether led is High or led is low. But this process works fine through arduino serial monitor and it effects led and gives accurate result but when I send string through java there is no any effect on led i.e led remains off in every situation. why? I need some help regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Arduino IDE menu to see the port being used.]

Adding to ChatterOne's answer slightly, if you're using the normal Arduino IDE, you can check the port number by going to Tools, Port, and selecting one. (Apologies, I don't have enough reputation to simply comment this on his answer (New to the site), but seems like useful enough info to avoid skipping due to that.)